# Regex match for singular version BUT NOT plural in R

Tags: r, regex

I might be missing something very obvious but how can I write efficient code to get all matches of a singular version of a noun but NOT its plural? for example, I want to match

**angel investor**

**angel**

BUT NOT

**angels**

**try angels**

If I try

```
grep("angel ", string)
```

Then a string with JUST the word
**angel**
won't match.

Please help!

Comment: pattern can be like angel\s?

Comment: like grep("angel\s", string)?

Comment: "angel\s?" ? is part of the pattern, which means optional space character

Comment: Do you want to match **only** the word `angel`? Or some other words also? Does `\bangel\b` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use word-boundary markers `\\b`:

```
x <- c("angel investor", "angel","angels", "try angels")

grep("\\bangel\\b", x, value = T)
[1] "angel investor" "angel"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach. It  still believe there are other excellent ways to solve this problem.

```
df <- data.frame(obs = 1:4, words = c("angle", "try angles", "angle investor", "angles"))

df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(words, "(?<=[ertkgwmnl])s\\b"))
#     obs        words
# 1   1          angle
# 2   3 angle investor
```